# C function not being called

Tags: c, function

```
vector_t solve(board_t src, board_t dest){
    printf("solve was called here");
    queue_t q;
    q.start = 0;
    q.end = 0;
    int visited[15116544];
    board_t parent[15116544];
    q.qu[q.end] = src;
    q.end = q.end + 1;
    visited[ord(src)] = L;
    while (q.start != q.end){
        board_t u = q.qu[q.start];
        q.start = q.start + 1;
        if (is_same(u, dest)){
            vector_t moves;
            moves.ind = 0;
            board_t c = u;
            int o = ord(c);
            while (!is_same(c, src)){
                moves.v[moves.ind] = visited[o];
                moves.ind = moves.ind + 1;
                c = parent[o];
                o = ord(c);
            }
            vector_t reversed_moves = rev(moves);
            return reversed_moves;
        }
        pair_t spacecoord;
        spacecoord = find_space(u);
        board_t a =up(u, spacecoord);
        board_t b =down(u, spacecoord);
        board_t c =left(u, spacecoord);
        board_t d =right(u, spacecoord);
        int aord = ord(a);
        int bord = ord(b);
        int cord = ord(c);
        int dord = ord(d);
        if (!visited[aord]){
            visited[aord] = U;
            parent[aord] = u;
            q.qu[q.end] = a;
            q.end = q.end + 1;
        }
        if (!visited[bord]){
            visited[bord] = D;
            parent[bord] = u;
            q.qu[q.end] = b;
            q.end = q.end + 1;
        }
        if (!visited[cord]){
            visited[cord] = L;
            parent[cord] = u;
            q.qu[q.end] = c;
            q.end = q.end + 1;
        }
        if (!visited[dord]){
            visited[dord] = R;
            parent[dord] = u;
            q.qu[q.end] = d;
            q.end = q.end + 1;
        }
    }
    assert(0);
}

int main(){
    board_t src, dest;
    printf("Enter src \n");
    //read_board(src);
    printf("Enter dest \n");
    //read_board(dest);
    src.b[0][0] = 6;
    src.b[0][1] = 4;
    src.b[0][2] = 1;
    src.b[1][0] = 1;
    src.b[1][1] = 1;
    src.b[1][2] = 1;
    src.b[2][0] = 1;
    src.b[2][1] = 1;
    src.b[2][2] = 1;
    dest.b[0][0] = 1;
    dest.b[0][1] = 6;
    dest.b[0][2] = 1;
    dest.b[1][0] = 1;
    dest.b[1][1] = 1;
    dest.b[1][2] = 1;
    dest.b[2][0] = 1;
    dest.b[2][1] = 1;
    dest.b[2][2] = 1;
    vector_t moves;
    printf("just before calling solve");
    moves = solve(src, dest);
    print_moves(moves);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is part of a much larger code of a game solver I am making for college. Every function and datatype is defined supposedly correctly. The function "solve" is not being called at all here. On trying to figure out the exact issue, I tried some print statements. The "just before calling solve" is printed, but "solve was called here" is not printed, and the program ends without any output. There are no compilation error in VS code either. What is the problem in this?

I am a beginner so I dont know much about this. I tried using online compilers, but they did the same, or gave a segmentation fault. ChatGPT says this could be a runtime error, but I dont know how to debug those....and what even is exactly the runtime error in this??

Comment: Be sure to put a `\n` at the end of all of your `printf()` strings, otherwise your strings won't always get flushed to stdout immediately and you'll be very confused about what has or has not been executed yet.

Comment: Perhaps `solve` is called and the program exits because it crashes. You should use a debugger and step through the code to see what is happening. You might also consider putting together a [mcve] so others could compile and run the code.

Comment: You might also want to declare your 15116544-item-long arrays as `static` to avoid putting them on the stack, as placing 30-million-plus items onto the stack is probably asking for trouble.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=segfault+%5Bc%5D+large+array

Comment: As Jeremy Friesner says, placing in the order of 100 MB on the stack is likely to cause trouble, and that trouble is likely to occur before the `printf` in the function is called. Having a function which locally uses that much memory is probably also an indication that a different data structure should be used.